# BIRT Report Designer - Tab layout

Tags: tabs, report, birt

I am trying to find a way to create a report in BIRT that allows Tabs to be used for content that is related to the same data, but we would like it to be separated into logical segments. Each segment would have a tab that you could click on to view the data for that segment.

Is there any way to do this in BIRT?  I see there is no obvious solution out of the box, but is there a plugin or hack that can allow this type of report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One relatively simple approach to implementing tabbed reporting in BIRT that I have seen:

- Use a separate report for each tab.
- Set up a grid at the top of each report with title cells for each tab, with borders and/or colours set to indicate which is the current tab.

  - The simplest ways to do this would be to set borders to solid on all sides of the inactive tabs and no border on the bottom of the cell for the active tab, and/or to set the colour combinations of the active tab's title cell to be the reverse of the inactive tabs' cells.
- Set up hyperlinks in the title cells of each of the inactive tabs to link to the relevant reports.